# How to transform link extraction into valid element with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, getattribute

I need to transform the return of the URL I'm extracting into a valid element.

the code captures the URLs and then enters each one of them to extract data from the page

terminal exit
[image]

terminal error
[image]

```
links = []
classe = driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, "//*[@class='LinksShowcase_UrlContainer__kMj_n']/p")
for i in classe:
    sleep(0.5)
    links.append(i)
    print(links)
    sleep(2)
for linkAtual in links:
    driver.get(linkAtual)
```

I cannot share the link, as it is a platform that needs to create an account and be accepted, but the link is as text within the TAG 'P', follow the image of the page

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Link should be attached the `anchor` tag with `href` attribute. Please post the relevant HTML or share the page link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements` method return a list of **WebElement** objects.
These are **not** links (strings).
WebElement is a reference, a pointer to physical web element on the web page.
WebElement may containg `href` attribute that normally contains some link.
As mentioned by KunduK `anchor` elements are normally containing links, not `p` tag elements.
So, in case elements you collecting are containing links you can **extract** these links from the WebElement objects and use them later.
I can't debug this code since you did not share a link to page you working on as well as you did not share all your Selenium code, but I guess something like following can work:

```py
links = []
classe = driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, "//*[@class='LinksShowcase_UrlContainer__kMj_n']/p")
for i in classe:
    link = i.get_attribute("href")
    print(link)
    links.append(link)
for linkAtual in links:
    driver.get(linkAtual)
```

**UPD**
In your case it is not `href` attribute but a text content. So, you can simply extract the text as following:

```py
links = []
classe = driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, "//*[@class='LinksShowcase_UrlContainer__kMj_n']/p")
for i in classe:
    link = i.text
    print(link)
    links.append(link)
for linkAtual in links:
    driver.get(linkAtual)
```

Comment: I edited the text and attached the page images

Comment: OK, I see. Did my suggestion worked? If not what is the problem?

Comment: the suggestion didn't work because it doesn't have the HREF attribute the link is as text inside the TAG P

Comment: Ah, sure, I see. So, you can simply extract the text there. I will edit my answer now. Let me know if it worked now.

Comment: ok, everything is fine, code working

Comment: Hello, I had an error with your suggestion when I included it in all my code, so I created another question, if you can guide me through it I would appreciate it, thanks anyway.
https://prnt.sc/5i5Y2Ud8of0f

Comment: OK, I'll take a look

Comment: I managed to solve it with the help of the staff who answered the question, thank you.

Comment: OK, very good ;) I hope I will be able to help you next time